# Handlebars each statement can access data that handlebars won't access directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a simple help desk app I've been building, where user can make request for site changes. One of the features is being able to see all request made by a specific person, which is working. However on that page I wanted to have something akin to "User's Request" where user is the person's page you are on. However I can't seem to get it to work without some weird issues. If I use:

```
{{#each request}}
{{user.firstName}}'s Request
{{/each}}
```

It works but I end up with the header being written as many times as the user has request. However, when I tried:

```
{{request.user.firstName}}
```

It returns nothing.

My route is populating user data, so I *think* I should be able to reference it directly. Here's the route:

```
// list Request by User
router.get('/user/:userId', (req, res) => {
  Request.find({user: req.params.userId})
    .populate('user')
    .populate('request')
    .then(request => {
      res.render('request/user', {
        request: request,
      });
    });
});
```

Here's the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const RequestSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'new',
},
priority: {
    type: String,
    default: 'low',
},
project: {
    type: String,
    default: 'miscellaneous',
},
category: {
    type: String,
    default: 'change',
    category: ['change', 'bug', 'enhancement', 'investigation', 'minor_task', 'major_task', 'question'],
},
organization: {
    type: String,
    default: 'any',
},
assignedUser: {
    type: String,
    default: 'venkat',
},
allowComments: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
},
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
},
lastUser: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
lastUpdate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
comments: [{
    commentBody: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    commentDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    commentUser: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users',
    },
  }],
});

// Create collection and add Schema
mongoose.model('request', RequestSchema);
```

The rest of the code is at: https://github.com/Abourass/avm_req_desk

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how, the answer was to add the array identifier to the dot path notation:

```
<h4>{{request.0.user.firstName}}'s Request</h4>
```